# Xcode command line tools some headers missing

Tags: xcode-command-line-tools

I recently upgraded my Xcode command line tools and now I get errors when compiling stuff that compiled before the upgrade.

```
tools/px.c:7:10: fatal error: 'unistd.h' file not found
#include <unistd.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~
```

Before this upgrade, whenever I installed a new release of Xcode, I had to install the command line tools and additionally

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
```

After the latest upgrade, that file and the directory containing it does not exist any more.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the package on another machine where I have not yet upgraded.
Nevertheless the issue remain unsolved.

Comment: Any further info on this?  unbelievable that `unistd.h` not found